# boost posix_time: stringstream input fails

Tags: c++, boost

Any idea why this is returning not-a-date-time, instead of the time string? I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 using boost 1.55.0.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

using namespace boost::posix_time;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ptime t2;
    std::stringstream ss("2004-Jan-1 05:21:33.20");
    ss >> t2;

    std::cout<<t2<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "simple string" format you want is `YYYY-mmm-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff`.

See the [posix time docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html).

The day is on two digits, so try with `std::stringstream ss("2004-Jan-01 05:21:33.20");` instead.

[Live on coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3871354255b5245)

Comment: correct, thanks. I pulled that string straight from the boost documentation, so didn't bother to check. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/examples/general_usage_examples.html

Comment: Is there a list of acceptable formats somewhere? the posix time docs are not  clear. for example, it looks like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff might also be acceptable given the examples, but it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I think the three to_string conversion formats are acceptable, so simple, iso, and iso_extended. Hence `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff` would not be acceptable but `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS,fffffffff` would.

Comment: I mean as per the examples, the date-time separator `T` is *literally* "T".